# How to get the text-area content as exactly user entered

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my webpage i am using textarea to get the details form the users and stored it in the database.

**1.This is how the user entered**

[image]

**2. This is how it stored in the database**

**Our Needs: 1.WireSet 2.Amps 3.Lights**

Now i am retrieve the details in some-other pages  How to display the result as show in the image(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are displaying it in html, then use this:

```
text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var text = "Our Needs: 1.WireSet 2.Amps 3.Lights";
string[] items = text.Split(':')[1]
                     .Split('.')
                     .Where((s,i) => i % 2 != 0)
                     .Select(s => s);
```

Comment: The user can enter any kind of data text and numbers in any format.

Comment: If you are going to parse text than you need to have some sort of rules, or restrict the user to add items to some sort of listview control, otherwise it will be almost impossible to parse arbitrary strings.